# multiview iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, multiview

I have several different views in my iPhone app.  When the app starts, I will have logic to determine which view to start with (rather than always starting with the same view and leaving it up to the user to change views). One of the "views" will have several pages (tabs or table rows, not sure at this point... but the dominant view will need as much screen real estate as possible and having a tab bar/navigation bar always visible isn't desirable or necessary ... It would be like the Weather and Stocks apps.  My desired approach would be to start with the Utility app template and have a tab bar view on the "flipside view".  Which project template is best to start with?  Do I have to make changes to the template?  In which event should I put the decision logic to determine which view to show. If I do indeed use the Utility template, is it tricky to make the flipside a tabbar view without using the TabBar template from the beginning? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could start with the view based application template and have your view changing buttons call back to your app delegate to change the views for you like this

-(IBAction)goToSomeOtherView {
    yourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate viewChangingCode];
}

And in the app delegate, just clear out the current view and add the new view. That way you could have whatever animation you wanted in-between view changes.

Adding a tab bar is pretty straight forward as well. You can do it in interface builder and link up the buttons as needed.